# Ctrl+D toggles the OSX dock but I want it to be passed to the terminal

Tags: terminal, macos, keyboard

I'm new to Linux and have been playing around with manipulating files with cat

ie.

```
cat > randomNames
Albert Einstein
Marie Curie
Isaac Newton
```

now when I want to quit cat with `control + D` on my mac it just seems to toggle my dock?!

To no avail I've tried all options; what could be happening here?

Comment: @Babyy - thank you. Truth be told I had written in a similar style to your edit  - not sure why it displayed the way it did :/

Comment: It's possible that dock captured `Ctrl-D` combination, or you pressing not a `Ctrl` key but some other Mac key.

Comment: Agreed, @Seo-Jun Koh - Make sure you are using the `Ctrl` key, not the `Cmd` key. Mac has almost replaced `Ctrl` with `Cmd`, except for in the terminal (and a few other application-specific examples)...

Comment: 100% holding down control + d (does the lower case matter cause it's a lower case d) otherwise I would have to capslock (or shift + control + D) ...when I do command and D it just splits the terminal window into parts - really weird. I asked my prof and he was befuddled. :/ Sorry I know this question is lame ...

Comment: This is an old question - but I was facing the same problem today, until I figured out that an app by the name of "Windowmizer" I had recently installed had remapped `Ctrl-D` to minimize the current window to the dock. Disabling that mapping through the application's preferences fixed it.